# Calling method wrong

Tags: java, methods, calling-convention

I'm learning JAVA and trying to make a program that sums and averages an arbitrary number of integers. I've made two methods for this, one that takes the number of entries:

```
private Scanner takeNumberOfEntries(){
    Scanner numberOfEntries = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Number of entries:");

    while (!numberOfEntries.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Enter the right format");
        numberOfEntries.next(); 
    }
    return numberOfEntries;
}
```

and passes it on to another that reads the inputs and stores them in an array:

```
private void summingAndAveraging(Scanner numberOfEntries){
    int entryCountLimit = numberOfEntries.nextInt();
    int[] inputArray = new int[entryCountLimit];

    System.out.println("Enter the integer values");

    for (int i = 0; i < entryCountLimit ; i++){
        Scanner inputValues = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!inputValues.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("fu k you, enter again:");
            inputValues.next();
        }

        inputArray[i] = (int) inputValues.nextInt();
    }

}
```

When I try to call it in main, I get errors. I've tried both:

```
    takeNumberOfEntries instant = new takeNumberOfEntries();
```

and

Scanner instantiation = new takeNumberOfEntries();

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please quote the error message you are getting. You may also want to expand the title to make it more specific.

Comment: you cannot call methods with the `new` keyword... It's for creating objects...

Comment: It says: Multiple markers at this line
 - takeNumberOfEntries cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - takeNumberOfEntries cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Comment: where your methods actually resides in your code

Comment: In the class, above the main method.Shown in the order they appear in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate a function. You have to instantiate a class then call a function.

```
public class Class {

public void function() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class instance = new Class();

    instance.function();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate a function instead you can only instantiate a class.

`takeNumberOfEntries()` is a function.

If you define `myClass` as follows, you can instantiate an instance of it using `new` as shown below:

```
public class myClass{

}

MyClass instance = new Myclass;
```

Comment: yeah, but calling the function is the issue

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here, one syntactical and one conceptual (which may turn into a syntax problem later).

The first - you must instantiate a class before you may call any functions.  Instantiate the class in which those particular methods exist.

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

Second - you don't want to have those methods remain `private`.  They won't be visible to anything outside of that class declaration.  Change at least `summingAndAveraging` to `public` so it can be invoked elsewhere.